# How to compare rows in same table for Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Currently i have PLSQL code to process and calculate the data. But question is that can this be done without PLSQL i.e. using Oracle analytic functions something?

Table contains data snapshots of planned and actuals as follows:

```
data_snap_id    actual_dt   planned_dt  amount
------------    ---------   ---------   ------
1                           2014-10-01  20.00
1                           2014-10-02  10.00
1                           2014-10-03  5.00
1                           2014-10-04  10.00
1                           2014-10-05  51.00
1                           2014-10-06  10.00
1                           2014-10-07  50.00
1                           2014-10-08  15.00
1                           2014-10-09  55.00
1                           2014-10-10  100.00
2               2014-10-01  2014-10-01  25.00
2               2014-10-02  2014-10-02  5.00
2               2014-10-03  2014-10-03  15.00
2               2014-10-04  2014-10-04  15.00
2               2014-10-05  2014-10-05  5.00
2                           2014-10-06  10.00
2                           2014-10-07  50.00
2                           2014-10-08  15.00
2                           2014-10-09  55.00
2                           2014-10-10  10.00
```

And expected query output is following:

```
action_date planned_amount  actual_amount   adds    deletes
----------- --------------  -------------   ----    -------
2014-10-01  20.00           25.00           5.00    0.00
2014-10-02  10.00           5.00            0.00    5.00
2014-10-03  5.00            15.00           10.00   0.00
2014-10-04  10.00           15.00           5.00    0.00
2014-10-05  51.00           5.00            0.00    46.00
2014-10-06  5.00                            0.00    0.00
2014-10-07  50.00                           0.00    0.00
2014-10-08  15.00                           0.00    0.00
2014-10-09  55.00                           0.00    0.00
2014-10-10  100.00                          0.00    90.00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I'm understanding your question correctly, you can use an aggregate query with `max` and `case` to separate your planned and actual amounts, and then use a subquery to get your adds and deletes:

```
select action_date, 
  planned_amount,
  actual_amount,
  case when actual_amount-planned_amount < 0 
       then 0 else actual_amount-planned_amount end adds,
  case when planned_amount-actual_amount < 0 
       then 0 else planned_amount-actual_amount end deletes
from (
  select planned_dt action_date,
       coalesce(max(case when actual_dt is null then amount end),0) planned_amount,
       coalesce(max(case when actual_dt is not null then amount end),0) actual_amount
  from yourtable
  group by planned_dt
  ) t
order by action_date
```

- [Condensed Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/802bd/6)